# iOS 8 | Add image to UIActionSheet's button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiactionsheet

In iOS 7 and below , I added a custom image on `UIActionSheet`'s buttons , but it seems it doesn't work on iOS 8 and crashes ! , here is the codes :

```
  [[[sheet valueForKey:@"_buttons"] objectAtIndex:0] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Crashes due to :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIActionSheet 0x16d4abf0> valueForUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key _buttons.'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIActionSheet` is deprecated in iOS8, you may want to use the new `UIAlertController` with the `UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet` style.

I agree with matt, you should not use dirty ways to custom an UIActionSheet, the safest and nicest way to have an UIActionSheet looks like you want to is to create yours.

Answer (score 2):

It was always wrong to mess with the look / details of a UIActionSheet. The correct solution, both on iOS 7 and iOS 8, is to use a presented view controller whose view *looks* like an action sheet - but now it's your view and you can configure it however you like.